# Vim: ignore buffers open in other panes when cycling through buffers

Tags: vim, neovim

Let's say I have two panes split vertically with multiple buffers open. I have `file-a.txt/buffer 1` open in the left pane and my cursor is focused on the right pane. In the right pane I want to cycle through the remaining open buffers without going through `file-a.txt/buffer 1`.

That is, I want to ignore buffers open in other panes when cycling through buffers in another pane. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is to check if buffer is opened in other window. If is, then just execute `bnext` again.

```
function! Bnext() abort
  bnext                                " Go to next buffer.
  if len(win_findbuf(bufnr('%'))) > 1  " If buffer opened in more than one window,
    call Bnext()                       "  then call func again to go to next one.
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>b :call Bnext()<CR>
```

Comment: That is amazing! The comments are great and make it very easy to understand. Could you please help me understand the top line, specifically what the `!` and `abort` are needed for?

Comment: It's all described in `:h function` : 
_When `!` is used, if there is an existing function then it is silently replaced. When the `abort` argument is added, the function will abort as soon as an error is detected._